# Dropbox API: find the members of single shared file

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

My question is in regard to Dropbox file sharing API.

Since June 2016 file can be shared with specific groups and users and external emails. Until now, specific sharing happened on the folder level.

Is there any way to retrieve the file shared members from the API? I cannot find this answer in the documentation.

Today, in my application, I am doing it for folders by calling https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/list_folder_members. From the response I extract the groups and the shared members account ids.
To get the information about the accounts (display name and email addresses) I am calling https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_account_batch with the ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not possible to get the members of a single shared file, but I'll be sure to pass this along as a feature request.

---

Edit: this is now available via /list_file_members:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_file_members
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_file_members-continue
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_file_members-batch

Comment: Thanks. I have talked with DropBox support and they confirmed that. On the next releases they will ship  an API endpoint that will expose that information. Currentlyit is not supported.